# Using Drupal to pull content from Subversion on a schedule?

Tags: svn, drupal, e-commerce, synchronization

I have lot (1000s) of digital content files (images, videos) that are stored in Subversion.
I need to make these available for search/download to trusted 3rd parties. (search by name, category, tags, see image preview, download file direct from web server)

Currently there is a Wordpress + WP eStore plugin doing this, but the search is poor and content must be manually imported, which is a multi-step and time consuming task. (+ other issues)

So, I am looking for alternatives that I can hook up directly to Subversion for pulling down updated content automatically, and has a good search interface.

I've seen that Drupal + [ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) is recommended elsewhere for digital download 'stores'.

Also, Drupal already has Subversion modules for showing Subversion-based coding projects.

**Does anyone know if there is a currently a Drupal module that allows actual Content to be pulled from Subversion?**

e.g. the data itself (image, video) plus some metadata (probably stored as text properties) would automatically create an appropriate Drupal Node

If necessary I could write this myself, probably re-using the existing [Version Control API in Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol) for sanity's sake.  But I wanted to check first.

(I'd also be interested to hear if anyone has this set up for other digital download eShops e.g. Magento)

Comment: Are you up to programming a solution, or just looking for existing modules that may do it?

Comment: Sounds like you should store them somewhere else. s3 perhaps? Version control software isn't designed for binaries. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such arcane requirements are unlikely to have prewritten modules available. You should instead look into structuring the import data properly, perhaps with XML. FWIW, you can look at just scripting the svn checkout which sets up the data locally in an importable format and then use something like the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module to create nodes using [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush). In any event, there will be some inevitable wetting of feet.

Good luck.